# Entity Framework include for list of related entities loads initial entity by itself and causing error when edit

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

EF Core
I have entities

```
public class LogisticsZone : BaseEntityDeleted<int>
{ ...
    public virtual List<LogisticsZoneShippingPoint> LogisticsZoneShippingPoints { get; set; }
}

public class LogisticsZoneShippingPoint
{
    public int ShippingPointId { get; set; }
    public int LogisticsZoneId { get; set; }
}
```

I get LogisticsZone entity by id:

```
var entity = await this.repository.ListAsync(new IdSpecification<LogisticsZone>(id)).Include(x => x.LogisticsZoneShippingPoints).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

send it to client and edit it when it comes from client

```
public virtual async Task UpdateAsync(T entity, CancellationToken token = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        this.Context.Set<T>().Update(entity);

        await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync(token);
    }
```

It worked absolutely fine until I added LogisticsZone field to LogisticsZoneShippingPoint:

```
public class LogisticsZoneShippingPoint
{
    public int ShippingPointId { get; set; }
    public int LogisticsZoneId { get; set; }
    public virtual LogisticsZone LogisticsZone { get; set; }
}
```

Now when I get by id LogisticsZone it loads a list of LogisticsZoneShippingPoint (as before) but also sets LogisticsZone withing each LogisticsZoneShippingPoint 
and when I try to edit this entity I get error:

> The instance of entity type 'LogisticsZone' cannot be tracked because
>   another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being
>   tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity
>   instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using
>   'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the
>   conflicting key values.

Comment: basically you should find inside `this.Context` needed entity to update. by the other worlds this.repository and this.Context should be same, and might consider to remove `AsNoTracking()`.

Comment: @Vladimir I tried to change update to this:

var existing = await this.repository.ListAsync(new IdSpecification<LogisticsZone>(logisticsZone.Id)).Include(x => x.LogisticsZoneShippingPoints).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();

this.Context.Entry(existing).CurrentValues.SetValues(entity);
            await this.Context.SaveChangesAsync(token);

But it didn't save any relations

Comment: Are you really using lazy loading? Have you explicitly opted in by `.UseLazyLoadingProxies()` ?  If you are not using LazyLoadingProxies, for my own edification, please try removing the `virtual` keyword.  I have read in the documentation that if you do not have lazy loading enabled, that the `virtual` keyword does nothing, but I am concerned that instead of doing nothing, it has unknown side effects and looking for a reproduction of the error.

Comment: Which EF Core version you have?

Comment: When you add the bi-directional reference, you need to map it. For instance if you have a `.HasMany(x => x.LogisticsZoneShippingPoints).WithRequired();` mapping, you need to change that to `.HasMany(x => x.LogisticsZoneShippingPoints).WithRequred(x => x.LogisticsZone);`  so that EF can associate the two references and handle insert/updates in the correct order.

Comment: @viveknuna 2.1.1